# ERROR [BoneCP-connection-watch-thread] - Connection obtained from thread [http-bio-8080-exec-14] was never closed.

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, connection-pooling, bonecp

I am getting above error after calling store procedure. I am using BoneCP driver to connect Hibernate with JPA.

I am getting following exception, this exception is occurring after transaction is completed. I have turned on the connection monitoring which is throwing this exception.

I am using JPA 2.1 to cal stored Procs:
    StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery (ProcName);

Full stack trace is following.

```
[2015-Sep-03:10:21:33,500] ERROR [BoneCP-connection-watch-thread] com.jolbox.bonecp.CloseThreadMonitor:70 - Connection obtained from thread [http-bio-8080-exec-14] was never closed. 
Stack trace of location where connection was obtained follows:
 java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1588)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.captureStackTrace(BoneCP.java:572)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.watchConnection(BoneCP.java:561)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.postConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:79)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.getConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:92)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:553)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:131)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
 org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:96)
 org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:407)
 org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:378)
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:251)
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.execute(Unknown Source)
 com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.dao.impl.MarketingDAOImpl.UpdateImage(MarketingDAOImpl.java:95)
 com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.service.impl.MarketingServiceImpl.UpdateImage(MarketingServiceImpl.java:39)
 com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.web.controller.MarketingController.acceptMarketingAssetSearch(MarketingController.java:249)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:65)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

[2015-Sep-03:10:21:37,049] ERROR [BoneCP-connection-watch-thread] com.jolbox.bonecp.CloseThreadMonitor:70 - Connection obtained from thread [http-bio-8080-exec-12] was never closed. 
Stack trace of location where connection was obtained follows:
 java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1588)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.captureStackTrace(BoneCP.java:572)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.watchConnection(BoneCP.java:561)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.postConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:79)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.getConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:92)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:553)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:131)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
 org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:96)
 org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:407)
 org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:378)
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:251)
 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.execute(Unknown Source)
 com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.dao.impl.MarketingDAOImpl.UpdateImage(MarketingDAOImpl.java:95)
 com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.service.impl.MarketingServiceImpl.UpdateImage(MarketingServiceImpl.java:39)
 com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.web.controller.MarketingController.uploadAuthorImage(MarketingController.java:190)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:65)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I faced the same issue too. Please check in your code, you might using Java @Transactional annotation class(javax.transaction.Transactional) instead of spring framework's @Transactional class(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)

Spring has defined its own Transactional annotation to make Spring bean methods transactional.

Comment: It seems that java transaction is not completely compatible with BoneCP, or it could be due to some configuration issue.